# I want to use string into NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a date in string like

```
NSString Date = "Dec 21 2011";
```

I want to convert that string into date
as my date has special format so i am utilizing like that:

```
`NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTest = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterTest setDateFormat:@"MMM dd YYYY"];
 fromDate = [dateFormatterTest dateFromString:Date];

NSLog("%@",fromDate);
```

I am getting this log

```
2010-12-18 19:00:00 +0000
```

Can any one explain how can i get correct date.

Comment: Have you tried with [dateFormatterTest setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"] ?

Comment: It seems that your code has lot of compilation errors. Make it proper first.

Comment: @ Aadhira : i just randomly wrote that.

Comment: @ MartinMoizard : i used that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use lowercase `yyyy` in your date format:

```
[dateFormatterTest setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
```

The output with this new date format is this:

```
2011-12-21 00:00:00 +0000
```

Aside from that (main problem), you need to fix the following things:

- Add an asterisk (*) when declaring your string: `NSString *date`
- Add an @ to the front of your string to make it an obj-c string `@"Dec 21 2011"`
- Declare fromDate (you never declare it) - `NSDate *fromDate =`...
- Add an @ to the front of your NSLog - `NSLog(@"%@",fromDate);`

Your code should now look like this:

```
NSString *date = @"Dec 21 2011";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTest = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterTest setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
NSDate *fromDate = [dateFormatterTest dateFromString:date];

NSLog(@"%@",fromDate);
```

*Note I have renamed `Date` to being lowercase because it is conventional that you name instances in such a way as it avoids confusing them with classes.*

Comment: from your answer " You need to use lowercase yyyy in your date format: "

Comment: yep is there an issue with that?

Comment: I tried your code it gives me output : " 2011-12-20 18:30:00 +0000 "

Comment: @Maulik - the logged date will be in GMT, so 5.5 hours behind your time (India) since your date formatter is using your local time zone. This is normal.

Comment: @jrturton : thanx I didn't aware with it.. so how can I get proper time ?

Comment: That _is_ the proper time, there is no time zone in an NSDate. If you do stringfromdate back through a date formatter, you will get the local time again.

Comment: Thanks all and specially Alex : it worked with small yyyy. small issue is it gives me 2011-12-20 19:00:00 +0000 rather 2011-12-21.

Answer (score 2):

according to your last comment : you have to set your time zone.

For example:

```
NSString *date = @"Dec 21 2011";
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTest = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterTest  setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormatterTest setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
NSDate *fromDate = [dateFormatterTest dateFromString:date];

NSLog(@"%@",fromDate);
```